# Asp.Net Client side validation with Page_ValidationSummaries

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm migrating our project from .Net 2.0 to .Net 4.5.1.

I'm using the following code for validation.

```
   <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="validateTextBox1"></asp:CustomValidator>

   <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

   <script>
        $(window).load(function () {
            alert(typeof (Page_ValidationSummaries));
        });

        function validateTextBox1(src, args) {
            if (typeof (Page_ValidationSummaries) == "undefined")
                args.IsValid = false;
            else
                args.IsValid = true;
         }
    <script>
```

In .Net 2.0 `typeof(Page_ValidationSummaries)` is `"undefined"`. But in .Net 4.5.1 `typeof(Page_ValidationSummaries)` is an object with length 0. So validation doesn't happen properly.

If we run this code in .Net2.0 alert shows as undefined. But in .Net4.5.1 it shows as object. Why it differ based on .net framework?

How to resolve this?